# How can I write a function that adds the number of possitive number in a list

Tags: python, function

I am trying to write a simple function that takes a list of number passed as an argument and prints how many positive number is in the list.

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the code here. Can someone please explain this.

Answer (score 2):

You should return add instead of num. And you should initialize add outside the for loop.

Comment: Hi I tried that , Look at the code now and tell me :

Comment: I can't see any code

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,-4,-3,-2,-1]

def count_positives(lst):
  return sum(i > 0 for i in lst)

print(count_positives(lst))
```

the program above will print 4